# How to execute rrdcgi script from command line?

Tags: html

I have some rrdcgi scripts with HTML code which are used to show graphs on my webpage. When I try to run this script from webpage its fine and showing all details perfectly but when i execute this script from command line it shows below error and never returned to command line.

```
(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)
```

Can you please suggest me how can i execute these scripts from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1367)  The page is really big, so just scroll down until you see `(offline mode: enter name=value pairs on standard input)` in a code example.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer to pass null values in the script i.e.

```
./script.cgi < /dev/null
```

It solves my issue.